# Removing first and last item from double nested array if empty = true

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures

I'm working with `prism-react-renderer`, and it highlights my template string that I render in JSX inside MDX. This causes some whitespace when using it due to the spacing:

```
<Code>
{`
function test() {
    return "Test";
};
`}
</Code>
```

This causes `prism-react-renderer` to create an empty first and last line. I want to remove these first and last lines if they are empty. The array I'm working with has the following type:

```
type TokenArray = {
  types: string[];
  content: string;
  empty?: boolean;
}[][];
```

The outer array holds arrays which represent the lines. These inner arrays contain an object with a `empty` property.
I want to remove the first or last item from the outer array `tokenArray` if the line has its empty property set to true.

**What I've tried**

Look at the first item of the outer array with `tokenArray[0]` and get its only item ( how? ) and check whether that object has a property named `empty` with a value of `true`. If so, call `tokenArray.shift()`
The same can be done for the last item but I don't know how to access it with `tokenArray[?]`.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want first element in 2d array, then use like array[0][0]. (Like we are accessing by array[row][column])

For last item, it will be

array[last row][last column]

last_row = array[array.length - 1]

last item in last row = array[array.length - 1][last_row.length - 1]

Here is link for [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=68&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gawgOwIICd0EMRQLxQDeAUFFKJAM4BcUlw6AlsgOYDaAugNylQDGcZMBTBa9Jqx5kIAWzCgA-LQBGcOABsIWZDwC%20nTj2IDk9cohQ1YFtJhz4obXmTaFy4CFbYByLN4A0UN7K3hyBJsJCtL7KfAFQsvIgtAwArtC6-s5kOW4UnrQ%20cYHeACah4YKRokF8pRDxiaC0AGZY6pQZYdmu7lSF3mDx3gCOFfxVItFgI%20iNcs3k6OlQmdk5RH0Fjt4AHsMg4xFTQbsgAF7zSa3tnavd3MTGgmYtjOhmBMA2lGwADBx-o8TGZ1FhPuYkKY2N8oZQAHSaVjAAAWUAAtFAAIyA2GWGE-REoFiojHYjhE5FozE4nggjQQRFwFgACm8bw%20wHiHPogQARABJShQACiC1waQgSigfMCPOA8KauDwKqW6QAlHSXgymazvGD6PEDcB%20ULReK1VLaLKoMbFRaVV9lhBNcQgA)

```
type TokenArray = {
  types: string[];
  content: string;
  empty?: boolean;
}[][];

const tokens: TokenArray = [
    [{ types: ['a', 'b'], content: 'abc', empty: true },
        { types: ['c', 'd'], content: 'cde', empty: false }],
    [{ types: ['p', 'q'], content: 'pqr', empty: true },
        { types: ['x', 'y'], content: 'xyz', empty: false }],
];

const first = tokens[0][0];
const last = tokens[tokens.length - 1][tokens[tokens.length - 1].length - 1];
console.log('first', first, "Is Empty true?: ", first.empty === true);
console.log('last', last, "Is Empty true?: ", last.empty === true);
```